# How to filter multiple queries with search?

Tags: wp-query

My theme has two columns, each column has it's own query. When I do a search on my theme, it only filters the main query and not my secondary query that is on my second column. How do I do that?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: I have a main query and a custom query (new wp_query), when I do a search, it goes on my index.php since I did not do a search.php and only filters my main query. My custom query shows up, but is not filtered with the keywords entered in the sarch form. I do not think posting my code would help for this question :/.

Comment: Sorry, what part of that _doesn't_ depend on your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I do a search on my theme, it only filters the main query...

It's exactly how it should do. The url change only the main query (or better, the main query in the one fired by args in the url).

If you have secondary query on same page, they continue to work using the args that you pass to `WP_Query`.

So if you want secondary query also use the `s` param, pass it as argument.

```
$args = array(
  // ... you have your query args here ...
);

// next line check the main query for the 's' argument and if present add it to args
if ( get_query_var('s') ) $args['s'] = get_query_var('s');

$secondary_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// your loop here
```

Comment: Oh awesome! Also is there a way to see the full url (just for fun and maybe helpful for debug), so I can see the full query string?

Comment: What do you mean with *the full url*? The only url is the one you see in the browser... @Maxwell

Comment: Well the query string is part of the url, what if I want to see it? Or are each of the request parameters passed with POST? Either way, how can I see all of the parameters of the main query, even the one by default when I don't modify the query. I just want to see all of the query arguments if it's possible :).

Comment: By full URL I mean the one that isn't rewritten by Wordpress (by the controller or w/e it is that rewrites the url)

Comment: So you want to see all the query args. There are different ways, the more rough, but working and usefule is simply print_r the query object variable. For main query use `global $wp_query; print_r($wp_query);` For secondary queries simply use `print_r($secondary_query)`. @Maxwell

Comment: Oh yes you are right, but this will show a lot more than just the args.

Comment: @Maxwell `print_r($wp_query->query->vars);` if you want to pull out other info, but if you want to use for debug, that inf are importan: contain the posts reached, the count, the consitional tags and the raw sql called by WP_Query